# Largest Palindrome of two digit numbers

Tags: c++, palindrome

The program below is to find palindromes in products of 2 digit numbers (up to 10*11 for trails).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int res1=0
void palindrome(int mul)
{
    int k,res=0,count=0;
    int p=mul;
    while(mul!=0)
    {
        k=mul%10;
        res=(res*10)+k;
        mul=mul/10;
    }
    if(res==p)
              cout<<res<<"is a palindrome:\n"
        {
        if(res1<res) 
            res1=res;
        }
    }

int main()
{
    int mul,j;
    for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<12;j++)
        {

            mul=i*j;
            if(mul>10)
            palindrome(mul);
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code works for all that I need except for the largest palindrome.

My algorithm is like

1. Take the product of each combination
2. Use a function to check whether the result is palindrome if multiplication res is >10 and print the palindrome.
3. Check for the largest number by comparing with the previous number.

So I have stored the previous value in res1 variable, and I am comparing the res and res1 variables.

According to my logic it checks lastly (88<99) that is true.  Now the problem is how to print the last value stored in res variable?

Comment: So, your question is _how to output the value of a variable_??

Comment: So, you already managed to write code to output a variable, yet you ask how to output another variable? try transferring the knowledge from one to the other variable...?

Comment: you said **product of 2 digit numbers**, but you are multiplying single digit numbers??

Comment: is `0110` a palindrome, or is `585` one?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the Global variable `res1` that stores the value of the palindrome, consider adding a `cout` to output this value: `cout<<"Last value: "<<res1<<endl;` before you `return 0`.

Of course, I'd reccommend that your `palindrome` function instead accept and return `res1` to avoid having the global variable and some other semantic type things... but those are different issues which may not matter to you.

Comment: @MatteoItalia My 'favorite' anti-virus software confused my spelling. Thanks

Comment: Thank u very much yar. i got it. superb really

Comment: @bhanu If this helped you, I'd appreciate it if you marked the answer as useful or even marked it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code to check whether the input number by user is palindrome or not. The code also returns the reverse of given number.
Code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class palindrome
{
    int a;
    int f;
    int b;
    int l;
    int c;
    int count;
public:
    void getdata();
    void counting();
    void reverse();
    void display();
};

void palindrome::getdata()
{
    cout<<"Enter any number having atleast 2 digits";
    cin>>a;
    b=a;
    c=a;
}

void palindrome::counting()
{
    int count=1;
    f=1;
    do
    {
        a=a/10;
        count++;
    }while(a/10!=0);

    for(int k=1;k<count;k++)
    {
        f=f*10;
    }
}

void palindrome::reverse()
{
    l=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
    {
        int k=b%10;
        k=k*f;
        f=f/10;
        l=l+k;
        b=b/10;
    }
    cout<<"\nThe reverse of the number is"<<l;

}

void palindrome::display()
{
    if(l==c)
    {
        cout<<"\nThe number is palindrome";
    }
    else
        cout<<"\nThe number is not palindrome";
}

void main()
{
    palindrome a; 
    clrscr();
    a.getdata();
    a.counting();
    a.reverse();
    a.display();
    getch();
}
```